# Intermediate value theorem in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

What I want to know is: for a 'nice' function $f(z)$ (it has no poles or discontinuities) if I know its values on a closed contour $\Gamma$ can I tell if it crosses zero inside contour $\Gamma$ ?

I realize that knowing the values on a closed contour lets us know all the values inside that contour but I wonder if there is any simple way of telling if there is a zero in there.

Comment: Depending on the context, Rouché's Theorem might be very useful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: @GregMartin thats really nice, thanks

Comment: @GregMartin If we know there is no poles inside the countour, could we use $1/f(z)$ alone?

Comment: No, because that won't give a contribution of $1$ from each zero, but some number depending on $f(z)$.